# How to extract information from the command line?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, command-line

I would like to analyze the options passed via the command line using C++ and QT, without using external libraries. In particular, assuming that the possible lines of command are the following ones, what is the easiest way to analyze and extract the required information (*path*, *string*, *int_1*, *int_2*, *int_3*)?

```
--intrinsic <path> <int_1> <int_2> <int_3>
--extrincic <path> -solve -3D <string> -2D <string>
--extrincic <path> -verify -3D <string>
```

Comment: You can use `QCoreApplication::arguments()` and iterate over the items checking their content.

Comment: Maybe the new class QCommandLineParser can help you: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html

Comment: @avb Your comment is the answer, why not make it an answer and add a bit more detail.

Comment: I posted it as answer but @Nejat commented that it is not an answer but a comment. So I deleted the answer and added it as comment. Now I'm confused :-O and undeleted my original answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new class [QCommandLineParser](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html) can help you.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should comment on question.